# Not able to replace text using sed

Tags: shell, sed

I am writing a script and part of it involves replacing few parameters in a file.

I am trying to find and replace the parameter and need to debug sed.

`sed -i "s/"$DEFAULT_MAIL_DOMAIN = "padl.com";"/"$DEFAULT_MAIL_DOMAIN = "$E_DOMAIN";"/g" /usr/share/migrationtools/migrate_common.ph`

Target file:

```
# Default DNS domain
$DEFAULT_MAIL_DOMAIN = "padl.com";

# Default base 
$DEFAULT_BASE = "dc=padl,dc=com"
```

Script:

```
echo "Enter the email domain"
read E_DOMAIN
echo "The email domain will be "$E_DOMAIN".com"
sleep 2
E_DOMAIN_VAR=$E_DOMAIN.com
sed -i "s/"$DEFAULT_MAIL_DOMAIN = "padl.com";"/"$DEFAULT_MAIL_DOMAIN = "$E_DOMAIN";"/g" /usr/share/migrationtools/migrate_common.ph
```

Comment: Should the double quotes around `"padl.com"` be part of the pattern? In that case they need to be escaped: `\"padl.com\"`. The same goes for any other double quotes that `sed` needs to see.

Comment: Instead of showing us the `strace` which is not at all relevant here, please [edit] your question and i) show us your input file; ii) show us what part of it you are trying to match; iii) show us how you set your `$DEFAULT_MAIL_DOMAIN` variable before using it in the `sed` command; iv) explain what actually happens when you run the `sed`.

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend something more like the following:

```
sed -i 's|$DEFAULT_MAIL_DOMAIN = \"padl.com\";|$DEFAULT_MAIL_DOMAIN = \"$E_DOMAIN\";|' /usr/share/migrationtools/migrate_common.ph
```

Changes I made:

- changed to single quotation marks around the sed substitution. All those double quotes you had going on were bound to cause trouble.
- Changed from `/` to `|` for the sed substition syntax. This part is not necessary. I just prefer it. You can keep `/` if you'd like.
- Next I removed the double quotation marks around your search and replacement texts. There wasn't a need for them.
- Escaped the double quotation marks that are actually in the text of the file.
- removed the global flag at the end of the sed substitution. This looks like a parameter in a configuration file, it's only going to happen once per line (and probably once per file).

Comment: Single quotes will not work using variables like $DEFAULT inside sed code blocks.

Comment: @GeorgeVasiliou as I understand it, he's not actually trying to get bash to interpret any variables. Those are variables that whatever application uses that file interprets. The sed command is searching and replacing that actual text.

Comment: TopHat - no, both you and @George are only partially right:  OP wants to replace the value of the key `$DEFAULT_MAIL_DOMAIN` (so here `$...` should be treated as a literal string) with the value of `$E_DOMAIN` so the latter has to be expanded (it's the user input no ?) which won't happen with your solution because everything is enclosed in single quotes. As a side note: you don't need to escape double quotes when enclosed in single quotes.

Comment: Sadly the question originally didn't have the actual input file. About quoting quotes, in the shell you usually don't want to (not just don't need to) escape double quotes within single quotes: `echo 'foo\"bar'` will display `foo\"bar`, with the backslash. Though `sed` will eat the backslash, so here it's ok.

Comment: According to the standard, it's undefined what to do with `\"`. The `sed` flavours I know will ignore the backslash, I think, but there may be implementations using this for some strange extension.

Answer (score 2):

If `$DEFAULT_MAIL_DOMAIN` and the quotes are a literal part of the file, 
we need to use single-quotes or backslashes to escape them. So either of the following:

```
$ E_DOMAIN=foobar.com
$ sed -e 's/$DEFAULT_MAIL_DOMAIN = "padl.com"/$DEFAULT_MAIL_DOMAIN = "'"$E_DOMAIN"'"/' file
# Default DNS domain
$DEFAULT_MAIL_DOMAIN = "foobar.com";
...
$ sed -e "s/\$DEFAULT_MAIL_DOMAIN = \"padl.com\"/\$DEFAULT_MAIL_DOMAIN = \"$E_DOMAIN\"/" file
# Default DNS domain
$DEFAULT_MAIL_DOMAIN = "foobar.com";
```

In the first, the quotes are interpreted like this:

```
'.../$DEFAULT_MAIL_DOMAIN = "'"$E_DOMAIN"'"/'
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^           ^^^^  - single-quoted, literal ""s
                              ^^^^^^^^^^^  - double-quoted, var expanded
```

In the second, the whole thing is a double-quoted string, with the problematic `$` and `"` escaped. But not the `$` in `$E_DOMAIN`, since we want to expand that variable.

I'm not sure if the variable should be `E_DOMAIN` or `E_DOMAIN_VAR`, you added the `.com` suffix to the latter, but used the former in the `sed` command. In any case, `/`, `&` or newline in the variable will be processed specially by `sed`, but a domain name shouldn't contain those.

---

In your snippet, the quoting is slightly off:

```
sed -i "s/"$DEFAULT_MAIL_DOMAIN = "padl.com";"/"$DEFAULT_MAIL_DOMAIN = "$E_DOMAIN";"/g"
```

The first part `"s/"` is a quoted string, then `$DEFAULT_MAIL_DOMAIN` is outside quotes, so is expanded as a variable (probably to an empty string). The spaces are also unquoted, so `sed` gets multiple arguments, and will likely complain. `"padl.com"` is again quoted, but the semicolon isn't, so the shell will interpret it as ending the command.